# Div align when its fixed and max body width is specified

Tags: html, css

```
body {
   margin:0 auto;  
   max-width: 500px;
}

.div{ 
   text-align:left;
   position: fixed; 
   top 0; 
   width: 100%; 
   z-index: 1; 
   display: block; 
   height: 32px;
}
```

My body width is max 500px and I use `margin:0 auto;` to show the page centered. But in this way, the top fixed div doesnt obey to 500px middle rule.
I want it fixed in the center like whole body contents.
[image]
I tried to use `*{margin:0 auto;  max-width: 500px;}` and some other changes but didnt get what I want.

Comment: Give you code ,whatever you tried so far.

Comment: <div class='div'>top texts</div>

Comment: Add `position: relative` to your `body { }`

Comment: oh thank you though it didnt do what i was trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this condition you don't have to give max-width to your body try this:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">

    <!--place your div-->
  </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#container {margin:0 auto; max-width: 500px;}
```

when you place your div in container then they follow max-width rule

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are not dependent on each other. They don't actually change anything.
`max-width` is the maximum width that the element **can have**. It doesn't mean it **will have** it.
`width: 100%` means that the element (`div`) will take *100%* of the width of its parent - which is `body`.
So, in your example body has **default** width which is probably *100%* of the window and `div.div` will inherit that width from it.
I'd suggest setting this

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

You must also remove `position: fixed` from the div. CSS for the div should look like this:

```
.div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:left;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: it was exceeding 500px because div was in fixed position. If i remove <code>position: fixed</code> it wont fix where i want! got the answer from Deepak Manwal